# Add custom field in checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.1

How to add zone number and street number in magento 2.3.1 checkout page after shipping address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an small task...
Lets say you are creating a module in `app/code/Roy/CheckoutShipping`

You need to follow these steps to create your new module for this:

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php`

```
<?php
namespace Roy\CheckoutShipping\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor implements \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface
{

    public function getShippingFormFields($result)
    {
        if(isset($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']
            ['shipping-address-fieldset'])
        ) {
            $customShippingFields = $this->getFields('shippingAddress.custom_attributes','shipping');

            $shippingFields = $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']
            ['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

            $shippingFields = array_replace_recursive($shippingFields,$customShippingFields);

            $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']
            ['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'] = $shippingFields;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function process($result)
    {
        $result = $this->getShippingFormFields($result);

        return $result;
    }

    public function getFields($scope, $addressType)
    {
        $fields = [];
        foreach($this->getAdditionalFields($addressType) as $field){
            $fields[$field] = $this->getField($field,$scope);
        }

        return $fields;
    }

    public function getField($attributeCode, $scope)
    {
        $field = [
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => $scope,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
            ],
            'dataScope' => $scope . '.' . $attributeCode,
            'sortOrder' => '333',
            'visible' => true,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'validation' => [],
            'options' => [],
            'label' => __('Zone Number')
        ];

        $field = [
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => $scope,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
            ],
            'dataScope' => $scope . '.' . $attributeCode,
            'sortOrder' => '333',
            'visible' => true,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'validation' => [],
            'options' => [],
            'label' => __('Street Number')
        ];

        return $field;
    }

    public function getAdditionalFields($addressType='shipping')
    {
        $shippingAttributes = [];
        $billingAttributes = [];
        $shippingAttributes[] = 'zone_no';


        $shippingAttributes[] = 'street_no';

        return $addressType == 'shipping' ? $shippingAttributes : $billingAttributes;
    }
}
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="roy_extra_checkout_address_fields_layoutprocessor" xsi:type="object">Roy\CheckoutShipping\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Roy_CheckoutShipping_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_ShippingAddressManagement" sortOrder="10" type="Roy\CheckoutShipping\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\etc\extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="zone_no" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Roy_CheckoutShipping" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement.php`

```
<?php
namespace Roy\CheckoutShipping\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class ShippingAddressManagement
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeAssign(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setZoneNo($extAttributes->getZoneNo());

                $address->setStreetNo($extAttributes->getStreetNo());

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        }
        return [$cartId, $address];
    }
}
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\Setup\Patch\Data\AddStreetNoCustomerAddressAttribute.php`

```
<?php
namespace Roy\CheckoutShipping\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;

class AddStreetNoCustomerAddressAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'street_no', [
            'label' => 'Street Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'street_no')->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'street_no');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\Setup\Patch\Data\AddZoneNoCustomerAddressAttribute.php`

```
<?php
namespace Roy\CheckoutShipping\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;

class AddZoneNoCustomerAddressAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'zone_no', [
            'label' => 'Zone Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'zone_no')->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'zone_no');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\view\frontend\web\js\action\create-shipping-address-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            if (messageContainer.custom_attributes != undefined) {
                $.each(messageContainer.custom_attributes , function( key, value ) {
                    messageContainer['custom_attributes'][key] = {'attribute_code':key,'value':value};
                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-billing-address-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setBillingAddressAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setBillingAddressAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();

            if(billingAddress != undefined) {

                if (billingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                    billingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
                }

                if (billingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                    $.each(billingAddress.customAttributes, function (key, value) {

                        if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                            value = value['value'];
                        }

                        billingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;
                    });
                }

            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-shipping-information-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes , function( key, value ) {

                    if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                        value = value['value'];
                    }

                    shippingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                    shippingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;

                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address': {
                'Roy_CheckoutShipping/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Roy_CheckoutShipping/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address': {
                'Roy_CheckoutShipping/js/action/create-shipping-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'Roy_CheckoutShipping/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address': {
                'Roy_CheckoutShipping/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "roy/module-checkoutshipping",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "email": "info@mage2gen.com",
            "name": "Mage2Gen"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Roy\\CheckoutShipping\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

in `app\code\Roy\CheckoutShipping\registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Roy_CheckoutShipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

This should create both attributes :)

Comment: This is not working

Comment: This should work. Have you run upgrade, di:compile and deployment commands after this?

Comment: But i didn't get

Comment: Please make sure you have run commands that I have mentioned in my comments.

Comment: Thank you sir its working fine.sir can you help me i want to add two extra field building number and flat no , is it possible??

Comment: Use this module generator https://mage2gen.com/. Try option **Customer Attribute**. This will make your task easy :)

Comment: sir can you help me.i want to add some custom field in checkout page magento 2 the fields are zone no,street no,bulding no,house no, street name.is it possible

Comment: Have you tryied mage2gen.com module generator. this will make your task easy

Comment: Sir can you explain

Comment: Add separate question for this, and share link of your question here. I will look how can I help you on this

Comment: i don't know https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: Error occurred during "shipping_address" processing. Error occurred during "customAttributes" processing. A custom attribute is specified with a missing attribute code. Verify the code and try again

Comment: this is my main issue

Comment: sir zone number and street number added to checkout shipping page but it not working.Actually the two field visible in front end side.but checkout time i got an error Error occurred during "shipping_address" processing. Error occurred during "customAttributes" processing. A custom attribute is specified with a missing attribute code. Verify the code and try again

Comment: Error occurred during "customAttributes" processing. A custom attribute is specified with a missing attribute code help me

Answer (score 2):

I can support the other answer

This is a huge task

I added po box field. Initially used mage2gen as other answer. But parts of it have changed and needed more work to support later versions of magento.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Postbox

This should give you an idea on the amount of coding required

The plugin code in the other answer might cause issue depending on what version magento you are using